# Data Flow Task runs successfuly but wrong rows are updated

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I created a simple Data Flow Task, that has two Data Flow components (I'm new to SSIS, so the follwoing may be trivial):

1. OLE DB Source - it simply connects to some table on some database
2. Script Component -

   Its Input Columns are two of the table columns:

   a. Column `A` (`int` type) - whose Usage Type is the default ReadOnly.

   b. Column `B` (`uniqueidentifier` type) - whose Usage Type I defined as ReadWrite.

   I called the Input Name: `ABInput`.

   **Edit:** I added an Output Column - which is column `B`.
3. **Edit:**  OLE DB Destination - it connects to the same table as the OLE DB Source, and its Input Column is column `B` (that was updated on the Script Component).

Inside the script, inside the function `ABInput_ProcessInputRow(ABInputBuffer Row)`, I do the following:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public Dictionary<int, Guid> Dict { get; set; }
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
         Dict = GetIdsForB();
    }

    public override void ABInput_ProcessInputRow(ABInputBuffer Row)
    {
        if (!Row.A_IsNull)
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.B = Dict[Row.A];            
        }
    }

    // ... other generated code and GetIdsForB code ...
}
```

**Edit:**

The task runs successfuly, but when I then go and check the table on the database - I see that *wrong rows were updated* (in fact, the updated rows seems to be pretty random), i.e., a row with a null value on `A` has a non-null value for `B`, and vice versa.

I presumed that SSIS would take the rows that were added to `Output0Buffer`, and match them to those on the database's table (based on the table's primary key, maybe?), but apparently that doesn't happen.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you used MessageBox.Show(Row.A.Value.ToString()); to show the value and see if it is NULL or not?  I would put it right above your IF.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to have an output Buffer in order to update or insert the row itself.    You can't really update an Input Buffer.  It's only for GETting data, not SETting it.

Comment: @MguerraTorres, thanks, an OutputBuffer is indeed what was missing. But now my problem is that wrong rows are updated.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I'd suggest writing out your answer and then marking it as the answer.  This will help others out in the future.

Comment: I would suggest not updating the rows from C#.  Instead, make a "Staging" table that links to the table you want to update via an identifier, and writing to the Staging table instead.  Once that's all done, update the final table using the data in the staging table with a SQL Task.